# Rewrite from old url's to new

Tags: php, asp.net, .htaccess

I have webstie written in php. It very old website it has around 10 years and it has unsafe code and ugly layout. All I want to do is to rewrite it to asp.net but this website has high rank in google search engine so i can't change links to my website.

Is there any way to rewrite all old links to appropriate links in my new webstie without loosing rank in google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Permanent Redirects (301). See https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en